# Global sections of the sheaf associated to a graded module on Proj

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S_\bullet$ be a graded ring and $M_\bullet$ a graded $S_\bullet$-module. It's known that we can associate to it an $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Proj}(S_\bullet)}$-module, usually denoted as $\overset{\sim}{M_\bullet}$ by setting on any principal open set $D(f)$ (for $f$ homogeneous element of $S_\bullet$)
$$\overset{\sim}{M_\bullet}(D(f))=({M_\bullet}_f)_0.$$
In other words the grade $0$ of the localization at $f$.
I was trying to compute the global sections of such a sheaf, but I'm warried about the fact that what I've done is not true in general if not very silly. My observation is simply that $$\Gamma(\text{Proj}(S_\bullet),\overset{\sim}{M_\bullet})=\overset{\sim}{M_\bullet}(D(1))=({M_\bullet}_1)_0=M_0.$$

Is this always true? According to many sources (e.g. here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M7) I belive that instead there should be a canonical map $M_0\to\Gamma(\text{Proj}(S_\bullet),\overset{\sim}{M_\bullet})$, but not necessarily an isomorphism, but I can't find if and where what I'm saying is wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really like this question. Though it would be also nice in the answers to put some details on the intuition why this canonical map restricted to a sufficiently high degree of these modules (assuming $S$ is Noetherian) is in fact an isomorphism (see Hartshorne Exer. II.5.9 and Theorem II.5.19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the condition that $f$ be a homogeneous element of **positive degree**. For a quick and easy counterexample, let $S=\Bbb C[x,y]$ with the usual grading, except we swap out the degree-zero piece for a copy of $\Bbb Z$. Then $\operatorname{Proj} S=\Bbb P^1_\Bbb C$ and the global sections of $\widetilde{S}$ are exactly $\Bbb C$, which is emphatically not $S_0=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I like this example.

And about the canonical map from M_0 to the global sections I guess then that it's given on an element x by gluing the x/1 in all of the (M_f)_0, for an open cover of principal open sets D(f), isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Don't you mean $S_0=\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @quantum yes, fixed.